# Is it possible to dynamically import Variables.scss file in Styles.scss?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, sass

Two different client needs their own theme and their respective theme colors are saved in Variables1.scss and Variables2.scss files. On startup, application makes a http call and pulls the information like name of the company.  Now, depending on the company name, I want to make decision whether to import Variables1.scss or Variables2.scss.

It seems kind of tricky because compilation of SCSS to generate CSS is done in first place. And only after that application starts up and pulls the company information from database.

Building the application for each client by importing their respective Variables.scss file could be a simple solution, but if the no of company grows, this way would not be feasible.

I went through a lot posts which are kind of related to mine, but they either suggested a solution which creates lot of code duplication or they lead me to change the name of the classes throughout the application.

Suggestions from experts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: try these links:https://dev.to/adamaso/angular-6-dynamic-themes-without-a-library-2e9c , https://coryrylan.com/blog/theming-angular-apps-with-css-custom-properties

Comment: @RandyCasburn this solution always demands me to go through a particular page, which sets theme. If we could always load a particular component on start up, this approach would be helpful.

Comment: The app or root component is always loaded up in every angular app and every angular app has an index.(html) page that gets loaded.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you for the response and it works to some extent. The only problem with this approach is we can't update global styles.scss file with those variables and we have to write css class for each individual child component even for common css classes. Use of ::ng-deep may solve the problem but it seems like it's deprecating.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best approach here is to use [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

For `variables1.scss` and `variables2.scss` you know their structure and which properties they contain, based on that you can create the same properties using `CSS Variables` and then mapped into your application to a common variable:

e.g

```
  $background-default: var(--background-default)
```

And when you make the `Http` request load the variables dynamically based on the response.

Comment: How can I load variables dynamically?  Could you please explain in detail?